# How can I remove an individual name from a Group on the Autofill feature of Mail?

Tags: mail.app

How can I remove an individual name from a Group on the Autofill feature of Mail?
I can remove the individual from the Group in Contacts, but when I use the same Group to create a new email, it keeps adding the removed address anyway!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the name in the "Address book" application?

Comment: Have you quit and restarted Mail since editing the Address Book?

Comment: I've had this happen in Sparrow on the Mac and I'm guessing this is a cache issue because even after changing gmail group lists in gmail sparrow continued to have the problem. I'm guessing mail uses a cache that you might want to toss to see if that helps.

Comment: @jaberg: Sheepishly--I quit and restarted Mail, and now the offending names are gone. THanks so much, I was making it too difficult!

Comment: As this solved your problem, I went ahead and added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've edited the groups in the correct place — Address Book — but there's one more step you need to take. Mail.app reads the *core data* from Address Book when it starts up. After editing entries in Address Book you'll need to quit and restart Mail.app for any changes to be recognized by Mail.